# Angular TypeError cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a function named `crop`

```
$scope.crop = function (id) {
    var options = {
        template: "templates/polaroids_edit_crop.html",
        url: PolaroidsService.getPolaroid(id).polaroid,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    };

    $jrCrop.crop(options).then(function (canvas) {
        PolaroidsService.setCropped(id, canvas.toDataURL());
    });
};
```

But when i call this function i get an error at this line:

```
$jrCrop.crop(options).then(function (canvas)
```

which contains:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.crop (polaroids_edit.js:51)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
at ionic.bundle.js:53458
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
at HTMLDocument.tapTouchEnd (ionic.bundle.js:2975)
```

The `$jrCrop.crop(options)` does the following:

```
crop: function (options) {
    options = this.initOptions(options);

    var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);

    ionic.extend(scope, options);

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(template, {
        scope: scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        scope.modal = modal;

        return scope.modal.show().then(function () {
            return (new jrCropController(scope)).promise.promise;
        });
    });
}
```

I have to wait for the template to be loaded and only if it is loadedi can return the modal. How could i solve this?

Comment: I would need to see how $jrCrop is defined. If it is a service is it being passed into the controller properly, etc.

Comment: its a factory of an angular module. I guess the problem is the `return scope.modal.show()` in the `then` function. but i dont know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: AngularJs is asynchronous so there really is no concept of blocking and waiting like in many oop languages. Look at the AngularJs docs for promises. Currently your post does not have enough info for me to post solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should return `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl` result:

```
crop: function(options) {
    options = this.initOptions(options);

    var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);

    ionic.extend(scope, options);

    return $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(template, {
        scope: scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        scope.modal = modal;
        return scope.modal.show().then(function() {
            return (new jrCropController(scope)).promise.promise;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Note `return` before `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl`.